# Lightning Community CMS Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

I know the answer is probably no; but, any chance we can use the CMS components in our own lightening components? I imagine not since it's still in beta. Anyone know if the plan is to expose them for use within other components?

Specifically these components:

[image]

Comment: Hi, were you able to find anything?

Comment: Sadly no and I haven't tried to find a solution to this since last May. It's been a few releases since though, so maybe something has changed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like as of [Spring '21](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_use_cms_in_custom_lwc.htm&type=5&release=230) we got the ability to add `targetConfig` property type of `ContentReference`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Test ContentReference</masterLabel>
  <targets>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
  </targets>
  <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
      <property
        type="ContentReference"
        name="imageContentId"
        label="Test Image"
        filter="cms_image"
      />
    </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

You can also use `filter` to finder the CMS content type.

- [XML Configuration File Elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags)
- [Add Salesforce CMS Content to Custom Lightning Web Components](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_use_cms_in_custom_lwc.htm&type=5&release=230)
- [Use Your Salesforce CMS Content in Custom Lightning Web Components](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_cms_use_cms_in_custom_lwc.htm&type=5&release=230)